# Checking if a variable 'isset' and assigning it differently

Tags: php, loops

I have the following:

```
$front = $data->getFromTable('Front');
$back  = $data->getFromTable('Back');
$side  = $data->getFromTable('Side');
$top   = $data->getFromTable('Top');
```

I want to check whether these variables are 'set' and assign an image to them differently e.g.

```
if (!isset($front))
{
    $this->setImage('bla bla');
}
else 
{
    $this->setImage('bla2 bla2');
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this rather than just 4 if/else statements, imagine I had 100 variables rather than 4.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use an array with all the values you could loop it and do it all with less lines of code. Maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly because it depends on how varied the 'image' variables are. If they follow a certain naming convention you could probably use a loop like below, if not then it will probably be lots of checks, but rather than having a huge if/else chain you could put the main logic of setting the image inside a function so it reads better.

```
$requiredFields = ['front', 'back', 'side', 'top'];

foreach ($requiredFields as $field) {
    $image = $field . 'NotSetImage.jpg';
    if (isset($field)) {
        $image = $field . 'SetImage.jpg';
    }

    $this->setImage($image);
}
```

Just a personal preference, but I find code to be more readable without using else statements, I also find that it's easier to follow if your if statement aims to evaluate to *true*, I don't mean the boolean true, but rather than checking if an image *is not set*, you check if it *is set*.

One last note, but it may be better to do a `empty()` check rather than an `isset()` check on your values.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the one-line if/else statement :

```
$front = !isset($front) ? $this->setImage('bla bla') : $this->setImage('bla2 bla2');
```

Comment: That is referred to as the `ternary operator`.

Comment: This still makes 100 lines of code for 100 variables, not the solution OP is looking for. Pigeons solution is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this:

```
$requiredFields = ['front', 'back', 'side', 'top'];

foreach ($requiredFields as $field) {
    if (!isset($data->getFromTable($field))) $this->setImage('bla bla'); else $this->setImage('bla2 bla2');
}
```